# Elasticsearch not returning hits for multi-valued field

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch with no modifications whatsoever. This means the mappings, norms, and analyzed/not_analyzed is all default config. I have a very small data set of two items for experimentation purposes. The items have several fields but I query only on one, which is a multi-valued/array of strings field. The doc looks like this:

```
{
   "_index": "index_profile",
   "_type": "items",
   "_id": "ega",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "clicked": [
         "ega"
      ],
      "profile_topics": [
         "Twitter",
         "Entertainment",
         "ESPN",
         "Comedy",
         "University of Rhode Island",
         "Humor",
         "Basketball",
         "Sports",
         "Movies",
         "SnapChat",
         "Celebrities",
         "Rite Aid",
         "Education",
         "Television",
         "Country Music",
         "Seattle",
         "Beer",
         "Hip Hop",
         "Actors",
         "David Cameron",
         ... // other topics
      ],
      "id": "ega"
   }
}
```

A sample query is:

```
GET /index_profile/items/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "terms": {
                    "profile_topics": [
                        "Basketball"
                    ]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Again there are only two items and the one listed should match the query because the `profile_topics` field matches with the "Basketball" term. The other item does not match. I only get a result if I ask for `clicked` = `ega` in the should.

With Solr I would probably specify that the fields are multi-valued string arrays and are to have no norms and no analyzer so profile_topics are not stemmed or tokenized since all values should be treated as tokens (even the spaces). Not sure this would solve the problem but it is how I treat similar data on Solr.

I assume I have run afoul of some norm/analyzer/TF-IDF issue, if so how do I solve this so that even with two items the query will return `ega`. If possible I'd like to solve this index or type wide rather than field specific.

Answer (score 0):

`Basketball` (with capital `B`) in `terms` will not be analyzed. This means this is the way it will be searched in the Elasticsearch index.

You say you have the defaults. If so, indexing `Basketball` under `profile_topics` field means that the actual term in the index will be `basketball` (with lowercase `b`) which is the result of the `standard` analyzer. So, either you set `profile_topics` as `not_analyzed` or you search for `basketball` and not `Basketball`.

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-term-query.html) about `terms`.

Regarding to setting all the fields to `not_analyzed` you could do that with a dynamic template. Still with a template you can do what Logstash is doing: defining a `.raw` subfield for each `string` field and only this subfield is `not_analyzed`. The original/parent field still holds the analyzed version of the same text, maybe you will use in the future the analyzed field.

Take a look at this [dynamic template](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/blob/v1.0.6/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json). It's the one Logstash is using.

More specifically:

```
{
  "template": "your_indices_name-*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "omit_norms": true
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "omit_norms": true,
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gotit. I actually want the match to be exact like a textual id, using case, embedded spaces and all. I use the `term` query because I want to use the exact characters in each of the `terms` arrays. Can I set the entire index or type to be `not_analyzed`? If so when do I do this, before creation, after creation but before new docs are added, or after indexing? Could you show me the JSON, having trouble following the docs because they often don't give this information or explain the fields in the JSON.

Comment: Looks like setting mapping can happen with index creation but every combination of mappings I could imagine returns an error. I was hoping that the entire type or index could be `not_analyzed` because I don't know the actual field names when the index is created, only when docs come in.